# Laravel views naming

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, directory-structure

Should I separate a folder for singular vs plural views for blade? I mean, for API best practices, I read that if you display multiple items, use plural while singular if you wish to display only 1 item. Should I also do this with views?

For example, create views/articles folder for index.blade.php (display all items) and views/article folder to render single item like create/edit etc. (if there are others)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, this is totally fine:

```
.
└── resources
    └── views
        └── articles
            ├── index.blade.html // plural
            ├── detail.blade.html // singular
            └── edit.blade.html // singular edit
```

Comment: Yeah currently this is how I do it on my project. So in the url, it will always display `articles` to display all items(plural) and `articles/id` to display singular items?

Comment: Right, this is how RESTful api url paths are done.

Comment: Thank you. At least I got a clarification on how should I do this.